# Add a button click to a jquery change method

Tags: jquery

I'm using:

```
$(document).on("change", "#PersonalInformation", function () {
  $('#Status').html("Saving...");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Forms/Data.cfm',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $(this).serialize(), 
    success: function(data) {
      $('#Status').html(data);
    },
  });
});
```

to submit a form. I want to add a button that the user can click as well (in the same form), and perform the same action. What's the most efficient way to make the button work?

Comment: Is `#PersonalInformation` a `<form>` element?

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have mentioned. It's a form.

Comment: Extract the code inside the inline/anonymous function to a function by itself and call that from the change and button click.

Comment: @freedomn-m I had considered that, but I want to use the $(this) as there are several more forms I'm submitting to the same url.

Comment: You could pass `this` to the function:  `function submitIt(form) { ..ajax .. }` `$(btn).click(function() { submitIt($(this).closest("form")) });` etc  (or use with `.call`/`.apply` to reset `this` to the form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `#PersonalInformation` is referring to a form, you can achieve what you require by hooking to the `submit` event as well as the `change` - which I also assume is propagating up the DOM from a `select` element. Then you can simply add a submit button to the `<form>` Try this:

```
$(document).on("change submit", "#PersonalInformation", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission

  // your AJAX code...
});
```

```html
<form id="PersonalInformation">
  <select />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks like it will work but if I hit the button it submits the form, how do I prevent the default html submit?

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg apologies  - I missed that. You can call `preventDefault()` on the passed event to stop the form submission

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed, I'll mark it correct asap.